# MVC web api GET parameter is always null

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, post, asp.net-web-api, get

Following is my ajax call

```
                     $.ajax({
                     type: "GET",
                     url: "https://localhost/api/Client",
                     data:        JSON.stringify({"SortExpression":"clientName","SortDirection":"desc"}),
                     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                     async: false,
                     cache: false,
                     dataType:'json',
                     error: function (data) {
                             alert("hi error buddy")
                     },
                     success: function (response) {
                         if (response) {
                           //todo
                         }
                     }
                 });
```

And my controller

```
public List<Customer> Get([FromUri] SortFilter filter)
    {

    }
```

and my model

```
public class SortFilter
{
    public string SortExpression
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public string SortDirection
    {
        get;  set;
    }
}
```

but my contoller always takes the parameters as NULL. where am I going wrong ?

Comment: Please provide the code for the definition of SortFilter and the assignment of "sort" in your javascript.

Comment: yes.. it just returns null values

Answer (score 2):

You're supplying a value, but not a key.  So while the model binder may be able to discern what a `SortFilter` is, it has no way of knowing what `filter` is.

Try wrapping the object and giving it a key name.  Perhaps something like this:

```
JSON.stringify({"filter":{"SortExpression":"clientName","SortDirection":"desc"}})
```

Answer (score 0):

GET requests are performed on the query string, which should not be JSON encoded.  POST, and PUT data may be JSON encoded, but not GET.  The reason your parameter is `null` is because the query string is a single string with no parameter name.

replace:

> data:JSON.stringify({"SortExpression":"clientName","SortDirection":"desc"})

with

> data:{"SortExpression":"clientName","SortDirection":"desc"}

You can check the WebAPI call directly by typing in the full URL to the web API method

> https://localhost/api/Client?SortExpression=clientName&SortDirection=desc

This will allow you to debug your data retriever, and page separately which should make the whole process much easier.